# Insert does not enter the date correctly even though it is in the default format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert some data in SQL Server 2008 Express, in a newly created database, and a new table. When I execute the statement, it throws me an error saying the following:

> Casting from varchar data type to smalldatetime produced an
> out-of-range value.

Am I making any mistake? The date format is the default format. Any ideas?

```
INSERT INTO WDL (grnr,kknr,lfnr,ktja,gebg,ktnr,kpnr,zszl,rsrn,chid,fpay,kcnr,res3,uknr,trnr,type,psnr) VALUES ('171114502', '161199999', '306', '2021-11-18 20:15:00', '2021-11-18 20:15:00', '171114497', '171114497', '0', '306', '29', '1', '16147256251234830750', '3', '161199999', '306','2', '29-1611-1-306')
```

Comment: With "interesting" column names like that it wouldn't be at all surprising to me if you have a mismatch between the values you're inserting and your actual columns. You will get this error when attempting to convert `'29-1611-1-306'` to a `SMALLDATETIME`, for example.

Comment: 2008? Really? That has been out of support for years now. If you are creating new databases with free versions of SQL Server I would highly recommend using the latest version, not a version that is 14 years old! Anyway, to answer your question, the format you are using is culture sensitive it could be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` or `yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss` depending on your regional settings. So `2021-11-18 20:15:00` is probably being treated as the 11th day of the 18th month, which does not exist.  Best would be to use the culture invariant format `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Adding table definition as text would help given the column names are meaningless in english

Comment: Older, *unsupported* versions of SQL Server needed a `T` rather than a space between date and time portions to get unambiguous parsing.

Comment: @GarethD 2008 is the version recommended by the manufacturer of a device which accesses the data, and they force me to use it in the office, I didn't choose it for pleasure hahaha, anyway they have already answered me so problem solved

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever [new versions do, too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d275b8f58409d9d4ed5496f15bc3791e) - this behavior hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

The temporal datatype of SQL Server have two differents SQL ISO Standard value specifications that are :

```
'YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.nnn' for the DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME
'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn' for the DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET and DATE
```

Why ? Because the standard has changed when the SQL:1999 version of the SQL language as been release. DATETIME dans SMALLDATETIME remains form Sybase that came from the early years of RDBMS area...

These two standard are not concerned by any settings of "culture"

**DEMO**

```
SET LANGUAGE French;

DECLARE @DTo DATETIME, @DTs SMALLDATETIME

SELECT @DTo = '20220131 23:59:59.987', @DTs = '20220131 23:59:59.987'

SELECT @DTo, @DTs
```

Note that @DTs shows a date of the next day due to rounding

```
DECLARE @DT2 DATETIME2, @D DATE, @DTZ DATETIMEOFFSET

SELECT @DT2 = '2022-01-31 23:59:59.9876543', 
       @D = '2022-01-31 23:59:59.9876543', 
       @DTZ =  '2022-01-31 23:59:59.9876543+01:00'

SELECT @DT2 , @D , @DTZ
```

Note that there is no more rounding for DATE datatype...

Comment: But why ever use the form that you can only trust with specific data types? It’s not like the form that’s safe with datetime is _unsafe_ with the newer types.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: there is indeed no need to deviate with `-`, but it's still worth noting that for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` no more than 3 digits of fractional precision in the literal are accepted. The newer types actually accept up to 9 (even though they can't ever store more than 7 -- but they'll round regardless of precision, whereas `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` will not). So if you have literals with more than 3 digits, you have to change tack regardless, and in that sense different formats still exist.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sure, but my point was not about precision at all, it was about the danger the dash introduces. The OP is using smalldatetime so there really is little reason to demonstrate a format that is unsafe there, and to be quite honest I don't know if we should ever be showing anyone how to use fomrats with dashes with *any* of the types.

Comment: @JeroenMostert [This format without dashes works fine, for example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d65803eb8354e43e7e3d666ad4a38c92).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes, I've linked to [your post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166772/97345) for similar questions in the past, no need to pound the drum on my behalf. :) My point was also not about precision (per se) but about the fact that there is no one, safe, universal, *complete* format covering *all* values for *all* the types (which I suppose really is too much to hope for in T-SQL, anyway). The `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff` format merely comes very close. (I've actually been bitten by the "`.fffffff` not allowed everywhere" detail in the past, in some generic code.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, agreed, but I still stand by the fact that `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff` works for datetime and also works for datetime2, regardless of language or dateformat settings, and if you need the extra precision you can keep the extra digits, and if you don't, you need to deal with them anyway. In all of this the `yyyy-MM-dd` format provides ZERO advantage.